# How to encapsulate shell execution into a function

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a script that needs to execute many commands, and I want to be able to **encapsulate the execution as a function**.

The sample functions are as follows

```
#!/bin/bash

cmd="redis-cli info | grep cluster_enabled"
cmd1="cmd1"
cmd2="cmd2"

exec(){
    local cmd=$1
    EXEC_RET=$($cmd 2>&1)
    EXEC_STATUS=$?
    echo "$EXEC_RET"
    echo "$EXEC_STATUS"
}

main(){
    exec "$cmd"
}

main "$@"
```

However, the following error is reported after execution

```
$ bash test.sh
ERR syntax error
0
```

But if I don't extract the execution command, it won't report an error

```
exec(){
    EXEC_RET=$(redis-cli info | grep cluster_enabled 2>&1)
    EXEC_STATUS=$?
    echo "$EXEC_RET"
    echo "$EXEC_STATUS"
}
main(){
    exec 
}

main "$@"

# stdout
$ bash temp.sh 
cluster_enabled:1
0
```

What causes this error and how to solve it? I really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Don't store commands in variables. Variables are for data, not for executable code. See [BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: Don't use `exec` as a function name - that name is already a shell built-in

Answer (score 1):

`redis-cli info | grep cluster_enabled` is shell syntax to execute `/path/to/redis-cli` and `/path/to/grep` commands, the first one with `redis-cli` and `info` as two separate arguments and second one with `grep` and `cluster_enabled` as two separate arguments, concurrently and with a pipe connecting the stdout of the first with the stdin of the second.

`$cmd`, as you use in `$(cmd 2>&1)` expands the `$cmd` variable, does IFS-splitting on it (note that it has nothing to do with what the shell does when it parses a command line other than space and tab are in the default value of `$IFS` also happen to be token delimiters in the shell syntax), followed by filename generation (so called split+glob), and executes the command derived from the first resulting word with all the words as arguments. So it's neither evaluating the code in `$cmd`, nor running the command whose name is stored in `$cmd`, for which you'd need `"$cmd"`.

So, it looks like you want to evaluate the argument passed to your function as code in the shell syntax as opposed to executing a command.

Also, `exec` is a special builtin of the shell already, and with several shells, including bash when called as `sh` or more generally is in POSIX mode, can't be redefined as a function.

So

```
run(){
    local shell_code="$1"
    RUN_STDOUT_AND_ERR=$(eval " $shell_code" 2>&1)
    RUN_STATUS="$?"
    printf '%s\n' "$RUN_STDOUT_AND_ERR" "$RUN_STATUS"
    return "$RUN_STATUS"
}

run "$cmd"
```

Comment: `exec` can be redefined (and used) as a function in `bash` version 4.4.12(3)-release. When you later unset its definition the word reverts to being the expected built-in

Comment: @roaima, not in POSIX mode. Sorry I had omitted to mention that.